server-side auth in Supabase with Next.js -- how to handle session
I have followed the following guide for setting up server side auth with Supabase and NextJS (with App Router).
I am trying to get session and perform logic with it in main layout.tsx file:
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
  // Get cookies from the request to access the session
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessToken = cookieStore.get("sb-access-token")?.value;

  // Fetch the current session
  const {
    data: { session },
    error,
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  if (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching session:", error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Session:", session); // Log session for debugging
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <TopNav />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

When I log in then I can see that a cookie is being created, but session logs as null

the way that I fixed it was by doing:
import UsersList from "../components/UsersList";
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";

export default async function Home() {
  const supabase = createClient();

  const {
    data: { error, user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching user:", error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("user:", user);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <UsersList />
    </div>
  );
}

in main page.tsx
